# Not found res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml Android 4.4

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

First of all I know, that on stack are hundreds of this question but my gradle is different that in the others.

**Here are my gradles.**

**projectGradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**appGradle:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.justfashion"
        minSdkVersion 15
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("najnowszy.jks")
            storePassword "asiunia"
            keyAlias "production"
            keyPassword "asiunia"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/NativeXMonetizationSDK_v5.4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/SuperRewards-3.1b.jar')
    compile files('libs/TrialpayAndroidSdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile files('libs/adscendmedia1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile 'com.github.leonardoxh:custom-font:1.2'


    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/personasdk1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-6.1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/heyzap.jar')
    compile files('libs/revmob.jar')
    compile project(':appGradeLib')
    //compile project(':sensiblefacebooksdk')
    compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiCustomizedSdk_v1.2.0_2015-11-13.jar')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiSdk_v5.4.0_2015-11-12.jar')
    compile project(':unity-ads')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.febaisi:custom-textview:0.0.3'
    compile 'com.scopely:fontain:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

**appGradeLib**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

**gradle proporties**:

```
#Sat Dec 10 02:02:41 CET 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

Please guys help me! This is the latest problem in my app. It's published and i'm fighting with this since 2 days :x i tried the solutions from the google but the error appearing on 4.4 kitkat all the time. Please, what is a problem in my gradles? I don't want to use 23 build, i prefer 25, but maybe it's neccesery?

## EDIT

Guys, anyone?

Comment: after update to build tools on 25.0.0 ,  some devices crashed with error -resource not found , try back to 24.x build tools

Comment: same issue here. I'm also using compileSdkVersion 25 and
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0". Any solution?
I've already tried everything.

Comment: Same problem using 23. I simple don't f***ing know what to do. Thanks Google.